# gulp, wiredep and custom sass file

Tags: sass, gulp, bower, wiredep

So I made a library that I can bower install using a direct link. I can use this library from another internal application by adding the library name in the dependency of the bower.json file. When other internal application does a bower update, the changes I made on the library will be applied to their application. This part is working very well.

Now, I'd like the other software devs to have freedom to change the styles. They can create css file directly and that will work. However, it's a hackish route. I can provide them the same settings file that I use.

So i tried putting that file in the main section of the bower.json but wiredep is processing it. I put it in exclude and the error is gone when I run gulp.

```
"main": [
  "dist/stylesheet.css",
  "src/_settings.scss"
],
```

this is the code that prevented it from being parsed by wiredep

```
wiredep: {
  directory: 'bower_components',
  exclude: ['css/foundation.css','src/_settings.scss']
}
```

Am I right that I'll have to create a new gulp task and put 'src/_settings.scss' as gulp.src like this

```
gulp.task('sasstask2', function () {
    return gulp.src('src/_settings.scss')
    .pipe($.sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css'));
});
```

I also like the generate css to be injected to index.html but not sure how to do it? Will wiredep automatically inject it to index.html?

Comment: I thinh you should not / can compile _settings.scss, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29635384/generate-sourcemap-for-each-partial/29693297 You possible have to create a local project.scss which imports the sass code from your library and uses the local _settings.scss or when not exists the _settings.scss from your library.

Comment: You should possible use the `includeSelf` option of wiredef to inject  the compiled CSS code from the previous step into your index.html