# Generate sourcemap for each partial

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm using the gulp-sass and would like for each partials he manages a sourcemap , I can do this using the less but did not see a way to do this with sass.

```
_partial.scss ( within it have to have a mapfile ).

_partial2.scss ( this also ).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the specification from sass-lang files starting with a `_` are not compilled. See also: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/215

So rename your partials with [gulp-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename):

```
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var rename = require("gulp-rename");

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src('./scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(rename(function (path) {
        path.basename = path.basename.replace(/^_/,'');
        }))
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});
```

Comment: it is my problem is for precisely this reason. but I will try your suggestion